# Speed up Google Map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, performance, google-maps

I have a asp.net 4.0 page that loads a Google map, with over 6,000 markers (and growing!)
I am loading the markers from my SQL DB, using a repeater control in the javascript like in this [this example:] (http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Populate-Google-Maps-V3-with-Multiple-Markers-using-Address-Latitude-and-Longitude-values-stored-in-database.aspx)

I have already added marker clustering and done everything I can think of to speed it up. 
Some of the markers are added during the initial load, but are not displayed on the map until the user zooms in. (via height:1 width:1 for the cluster icon)

Here is what I want to do, but I'm not sure if it is possible. I want to have my vb codebehind/asp:Repeater load the markers that will display initially. Then in the "Idle" listner, have it load the other markers so that they are ready once the map is zoomed in. 
BUT, I can't figure out how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Here is the bulk of the javascript:

```
 // configure options
            var map;
            var locations = new Array();
            var markers = new Array();
            var markerCluster1 = null;
            var markerCluster2 = null;
            var markerCluster3 = null;
            var markerCluster4 = null;
            var Style1 = [{url: '../images/m1.png',
                height: 48,
                width: 48
            }];
            var Style2 = [{url: '../images/m2.png',
                height: 48,
                width: 48
            }];
            var Style3 = [{url: '../images/m3.png',
                height: 48,
                width: 48
            }];
            var Style4 = [{url: '../images/m4.png',
                textSize: 1,
                height: 1,
                width: 1
            }];
            var mcOA1 = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 10, styles: Style1};
            var mcOA2 = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 10, styles: Style2};
            var mcOA3 = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 10, styles: Style3};
            var mcOA4 = {gridSize: 300, maxZoom: 9, styles: Style4, minimumClusterSize: 2};
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server" EnableViewState = false>
                <ItemTemplate>locations[<%# Eval("i")%>]=new Array(),locations[<%# Eval("i")%>][0]='<%# Eval("PType")%>',locations[<%# Eval("i")%>][1]='<%# Eval("Lat")%>',locations[<%# Eval("i")%>][2]='<%# Eval("Lon")%>',locations[<%# Eval("i")%>][3]='<div class=\"info-window\"><%# Eval("MDesc")%></div>',locations[<%# Eval("i")%>][4]='<%# Eval("Name") %>';
             </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate></SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
            function initialize() {
                var myOptions = 
            <asp:Repeater ID="MapOptions" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                        {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%# Eval("center")%>),
                            zoom: <%# Eval("zoom")%>,
                            streetViewControl: false,
                            mapTypeId: <%# Eval("mapTypeId")%>
                            }
</ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                        for (i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
                            if (typeof(locations[i]) == 'object') {
                                var icon = "";
                                switch (locations[i][0]) {
                                    case "A1":
                                        icon = "../images/A13.png";
                                        break;
                                    case "A2":
                                        icon = "../images/A23.png";
                                        break;
                                    case "A3":
                                        icon = "../images/A33.png";
                                        break;
                                    case "A4":
                                        icon="../images/A44.png"
                                        break;
                                    case "Furniture":
                                        icon="../images/Furniture3.png"
                                        break;
                                    case "Property Manager":
                                        icon="../images/PropertyManager3.png"
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        icon="../images/A13.png"
                                        break;
                                }
                                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
                                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: point,
                                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon),
                                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                    title: locations[i][4]
                                });
                                markers[i].setMap(map);                 
                                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {infoWindow.setContent(locations[i][3]);infoWindow.open(map, markers[i]);});
                            }
                        } // for




                // check to see which category is selected
                        var location_selector = document.getElementsByName('loc_sel');
                        for (var i=0; i < location_selector.length; i++) {
                            if (location_selector[i].checked) {
                                var location_type = location_selector[i].value;
                            }
                        }
                        show_markers(location_type);

                    } // function initialize() {


                    function show_markers (location_type) {
                        var temp_markers1 = new Array();
                        var temp_markers2 = new Array();
                        var temp_markers3 = new Array();
                        var temp_markers4 = new Array();
                        // if the markerClusterer object doesn't exist, create it with empty temp_markers
                        if (markerCluster1 == null) {
                            markerCluster1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, temp_markers1, mcOA1);
                        }
                        if (markerCluster2 == null) {
                            markerCluster2 = new MarkerClusterer(map, temp_markers1, mcOA2);
                        }
                        if (markerCluster3 == null) {
                            markerCluster3 = new MarkerClusterer(map, temp_markers1, mcOA3);
                        }
                        if (markerCluster4 == null) {
                            markerCluster4 = new MarkerClusterer(map, temp_markers1, mcOA4);
                        }
                        // clear all markers
                        markerCluster1.clearMarkers();
                        markerCluster2.clearMarkers();
                        markerCluster3.clearMarkers();
                        markerCluster4.clearMarkers();
                        // iterate through all locations, setting only those in the selected category
                        for (i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
                            if (typeof(locations[i]) == 'object') {
                                if (locations[i][0] == location_type) {
                                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                                    if (locations[i][0] == "A1") {temp_markers1.push(markers[i]);}
                                    if (locations[i][0] == "A2") {temp_markers2.push(markers[i]);}
                                    if (locations[i][0] == "A3") {temp_markers3.push(markers[i]);}
                                    if (locations[i][0] == "A4") {temp_markers4.push(markers[i]);}
                                } else {
                                    markers[i].setVisible(false);
                                    if (locations[i][0] == "A4") {markers[i].setVisible(true); 
                                        temp_markers4.push(markers[i]);}
                                }
                            }
                        } // for

                        // add all current markers to cluster
                        markerCluster1.addMarkers(temp_markers1);
                        markerCluster2.addMarkers(temp_markers2);
                        markerCluster3.addMarkers(temp_markers3);
                        markerCluster4.addMarkers(temp_markers4);

                    } // function show_markers
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution to this problem may be to fire a query to the SQL DB to fetch all the markers when the map is in the idle state.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    fetchMarkersfromDB();
});
```

And in the initialize() function pass both this listener and also the showMarker() function call. So that whenever the maps are initialized and displayed the markers at current zoom position would be displaced and during the idle phase the query in the backgroud would fetch remaining markers that can be shown in the next or consequent zoom levels. This way the markers would be ready and performance will be better.

Hope this would help!!

Comment: Thank you AniV,

That makes perfect sense.

What do I do with fetchMarkersfromDB();? That is a call to another javascript function, correct? How to I get it to trigger a function in my code behind? I don't want to have the javascript access the DB directly, for the sake of the obvious security issues.

Thank you again